# narrowing with `in` when property is a generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, narrowing

I was trying to write a helper function that would compare select properties from a pair of union typed objects. If the property is present, do further checks. I can do this by casting to any, but that is obviously not ideal type safety.

Use of `if (prop in obj) { ... obj[prop] ...` will only work if `prop` is common property (intersection) or is literally typed. Narrowing fails when `prop` is generic.

Here is a distilled amount of code to narrowing issue.

```
type A = { propA: string }
type B = { propB: string }
type AorB = A | B;
type anyKeyOf<T> = T extends object ? keyof T : never;

function check1<T extends anyKeyOf<AorB>>(obj: AorB, property: T): string | undefined {
  if (property in obj) {
    return `found ${property} with value of ${obj[property]}`; // Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'AorB'.(2536)
  }
  return undefined;
}

function check2<T extends 'propA'>(obj: AorB, property: T): string | undefined {
  if (property in obj) {
    return `found ${property} with value of ${obj[property]}`; // Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'AorB'.(2536)
  }
  return undefined;
}

function check3(obj: AorB, property: 'propA'): string | undefined {
  if (property in obj) {
    return `found ${property} with value of ${obj[property]}`; // Okay
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&pretty=true&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=2#code/PTAEBcE8AcFMGcCGAzWpEDtKgPbNAK4YCWOGo0ATjnJVKAMYAWsDA1sRgOYBQPUcUAEFQAXlABvCtWhCAXKHjhKnLqAC+-GGgBCYydJo6FSldw1bBQnJT3iRAH1A6A3JbSZIAaViQA8sgAPAAqAHz6waCwAB7gsBgAJvC4AEYAVqzgoAD8oGy+eKCRChiwAG6wlG48yEQM4KTkzKxsAIwhUbHxSehYPv5B1rahoQAUOOkKQzoANIa0UArBAJQmyqqgTkQJsMicsAmSPKCgxPijVDSV9JypactHJyeUsOAElOQABsg426AAJBJLgtIOpQAB3YjgJigMqIAA2BDQhUBEzSAG1gddIABddSfFygEBFbSgADkwTJjEwGBwWRSaAI8AOEBwp0SMQgpLJ0zJADpRgAmACsAGYAGzLY4WZ6vd7kba7fYJNyaGp1BpkRgsdiCjoxOKJZJk4FCMljNFTGyzebYparRTrcxbDl7UqHCTSs6gC4ybHsu4PT1PUAvN4fUDfX6JAFAv10UEQqEwuGI5H4VHpTHxqB4glEsDBbmU6kYWn0xnMw7gNmcHbRLmCHnW-lCsWS6WaWXhhWu5Wqvi1DD1Rralqi8aTYTWuZYhMKE0yM0O0wbF07N0s4Onc5zm7kNFB6Xd+WRn5-QF7xOQ6GwhFI3AZiRo7NXBN5wnEvxsRCQTvSsNT0VTcVR4NV1WHTVyAwRBKGocEADEbAAYR1Nh9S6I1em8XwAkCaYRknNIrVsWcc0ge0FDRU5kikYISJ0dFghxDRHlDOUIyvAM0QHIA)

Is there a way to write this, or am I running up against a limitation?

I additionally attempted to establish a type narrowing helper, but it is blocked by a similar issue.

```
function narrowForCheck<T extends anyKeyOf<AorB>>(obj: AorB, property: T): obj is { T: AorB[T] } {
  return property in obj;
}
```

Comment: Right, `in` won't narrow an object to one with a generic key.  You can indeed build a type guard function, though, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJXXrN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm kinda disappointed that TS 4.9 doesn't cover this. They *did* say that they added better narrowing with `in`, but I guess they can't cover all corners.

Comment: @jcalz, I think that type guard will do the trick.

Comment: I would definitely change type K restriction to just the possible keys of T which will prevent attempts to use the guard where no success is possible.
`function narrowForCheck<T extends object, K extends anyKeyOf<T>>(obj: T, property: K): obj is Extract<T, Record<K, any>>`